# Accessing C# Static variable within a UnityScript

Tags: c#, static, unity-game-engine, unityscript

So I have a sort of interesting conundrum. I'm working on a project with someone else. All their code is in C#, and all mine is in Unityscript. It mostly works because my script handles the GUI only and references his script. I've read up on how to do this, so my script is in the standard assets folder while his is in a different folder, so the compile order should be correct and that is not the problem. My issue is this. I need to import data from one of his scripts that itself is importing that data from a different script.

Relevant code:
My code.js:

```
var selectedRobot : Robot = PlayGame.selectedRobot;
```

PlayGame.cs code:

```
public static Robot selectedRobot;
```

Robot.cs is an entire script setting up the data for PlayGame. Currently I am getting an error that reads: "The name 'Robot' does not denote a valid type ('not found'). How do I get it to work correctly so it imports the data correctly?

Screenshots:
[image: Unitysript in standard assets, C# in different sub folder]
[image: C# in standard assets, Unity script in main folder]

Comment: Use C#. C# and UnityScript files don't communicate together very well. `Robot selectedRobot = PlayGame.selectedRobot;`. C# offers much faster compile times than UnityScript too, which is great in the long-run (in-editor compile times get longer and longer with UnityScript, not recommended, speaking from experience here).

Comment: I don't know C# and I don't think I can learn enough C# in the two or so weeks I have to do this to replicated all of the things I've already done with the unityscript.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the C# files in the `Standard Assets` folder so they are compiled before the `UnityScript` files.

[image]

Comment: The compile order isn't the problem, and if you had read my question, you'd know that. Originally I had them in the same folder but my script wasn't seeing his at all, but when I moved my into the standard assets folder, it worked just fine except for this one line. (There are some other variables that are imported, this is just the only one that isn't working)

Comment: @MechaScoots You are wrong! I read your question and I understand this problem extremely well. You should read my answer again. You have to **move the `C#` scripts into the `Standard Assets` folder**, *not* the `UnityScripts`.

Comment: Sorry, but no, I am not. I did exactly as you suggested, and now it won't recognize the other imports from that file. If I put them back the way I had it, then this is the only line of code that has an issue. Its only this one line that has an issue.

Comment: @MechaScoots What are these "other imports"? Also when you say it won't recognize the "other imports" after you did what I suggested, it's recognizing the `static variable` you wanted above for the question isn't? I get the feeling these "other imports" are a different issue.

Comment: Okay, I added some screen shots of what I'm seeing. The first one is when the unityscript is in the standard assets folder and the C# is in a different sub folder in the larger assets folder. The second one is when the unityscript is in the larger assets folder and the C# is in the standard assets folder. Oddly, if I have C# in standard assets and unityscript in a different sub folder just called scripts (same subfolder as above), it has the same result as the first case.

Comment: I looked into it further and discussed it with my partner. It may be that Robot is an abstract class that is causing the issue.